# Full-Calendar-Plugin Change Table

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, fullcalendar, cakephp-3.0

I have a small question. In my Cakephp 3.6 project I used the **CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin plugin** from **curtisblack2004**.

https://github.com/curtisblack2004/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin

I installed the plugin and everything works fine. I want to change the name of the table from "events" (used in the plugin) to "lessons" and completely change the structure. Where can I do that? Can someone help me ? Maybe it's a trivial thing to do, but I'm stuck and I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the repository of plugin, you may follow these quick steps:

1- change the tables names in the sql found [here](https://github.com/curtisblack2004/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin/blob/master/Config/FullCalendar.sql)
2- change your models/controllers names based on that.
example, if your your events tables becomes >lessons>, then in controller folder, EventsController.php should become LessonsController.php. You need to rename Everything related to Events into Lessons, in differents folders.